# why I get the error Apparently jsonStoreEnabled is not set to true , and I did indeed set it to true?

Tags: java, json, twitter4j

I am new to Twitter4j and I am trying to get tweets from twitter in a JSON
form 
but I am getting an exception.
I ran this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        try {
       //Establish Connection to Twitter App
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setJSONStoreEnabled(true);
            twitter=  new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getSingleton();
            twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKeyStr, consumerSecretStr);
            AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken(accessTokenStr,
                    accessTokenSecretStr);
            twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
        //////
       ArrayList<String> JsonTweets =new ArrayList<String>();
             QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query("abc"));
             List<Status> resulted_tweets = result.getTweets();
              for(Status tweet :resulted_tweets)
              {
                String json = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(tweet);
                JsonTweets.add(json);
              }
              System.out.println((Arrays.toString( JsonTweets.toArray())));


        }
            catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
```

and all what i get is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Apparently jsonStoreEnabled is not set to true.
at twitter4j.TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(TwitterObjectFactory.java:32)
at JavaTweet.main(JavaTweet.java:86)
```

althought I did set it to true in line number 6.
I am planning to use the jsonString to add it to a json object and look for some properties in the tweets I get in the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't configure the right instance. you pass your config to a NEW instance of the TwitterService class and then you get the singleton from that instance.. which is another instance that you never configured.

```
 twitter=  new TwitterFactory(cb.build()).getSingleton();
```

equals

```
  twitterFactory=  new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
  twitter= twitterFactory.getSingleton();
```

see it?

---

solved:

```
  twitterFactory =  new TwitterFactory(cb.build())
  twitter = twitterFactory.getInstance();
```

---

compare: http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html

Comment: Can you show some code that illustrates what changes the OP can make to fix the problem?

Comment: so how should I solve this ? is there a method to config the Singleton

Comment: so there is no way I can setJSONStoreEnabled(true) to my twitter variable ??

Comment: sure there is just don't get the singleton or apply the config to that object